# how to visualize entities of code first

Tags: entity-framework-5, code-first, edmx

I have a simple query.I have searched it many times but not getting satisfactory result.
         **I want to generate a diagram for all the entities(Code first) and relationship between them.I have total 19 classes so far.I have seen some articles on Reverse engineer code first.But I would like to see A diagram which looks like as created in Database First Approach.**

So far, have installed Entity framework Power tools in my visual studio 2013 But from there only getting two options---

1>Reverse engineer code first
2>Customize reverse engineer template

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Entity Framework Powertools "View Entity Data Model(Read-only)" feature https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj593170.aspx